# Rails Server Already Running even after server shutdown, only works again after exiting terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, localhost

I'm using Rails 4.0 on Mountain Lion.

I've looked at other questions on SO regarding this problem, but the answers I've seen are to simply delete the server.pid file in question. Doing so is only a temporary fix for me, as it reappears when I start the server again and does not go away. (Or rather, the PID number within the file does not go away). I'm not trying to run multiple servers, only trying to be able to shut down the server within the terminal and then start it back up.

When I open a fresh terminal and start a rails server it works the first time. If I shut the server down, and try to restart it again, I'm given the "Already Running" message. Now, what works is if I completely exit the terminal, and open a new terminal window. But this is getting rather tedious. Does anyone know what the deal might be?

Answer (score 1):

Use `control-C` to shutdown rails properly.

If you are running a tailing command, like rails does, you use `control-C` to shut it down correctly.

If you are running a console command such as SSH, PostgreSQL, or Rails Console, you use `control-D` to exit properly.

I have no idea why (maybe someone can tell me), but that is how it is.

Comment: Yikes, this is the frighteningly simple answer to my problem. For some reason I thought Control-Z was the command (I could have sworn I've been doing that all along for the server). Thanks, I guess I should be a little more observant.

Comment: Haha, now orries, `control-z` is used to move the process to the background. I believe if you use `ctrl-z`, you can actually still go to `localhost:3000` and still see rails running